# How to create a HalfOpenInterval with the lower instead of upper bound excluded

Tags: swift, swift2

This is an interval that ranges from 0.0 to 1.0 but does not include 1.0

```
var interval = 0.0..<1.0
interval.contains(0.0)      //true
interval.contains(0.9999)   //true
interval.contains(1.0)      //false
```

I want to create an Interval that ranges from 0.0 to 1.0 but does not include 0.0

```
theIntervalIWant.contains(0.0)      //false
theIntervalIWant.contains(0.0001)   //true
theIntervalIWant.contains(1.0)      //true
```

This does not work because left value > right value (right?)

```
var interval2 = 1.0..<0.0
```

This does not work and I have no idea why not

```
var theIntervalIWant = 0.0>..1.0
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Range`s in Swift are `SequenceType`s, which means that you can iterate over them, which throws in a few complications. For instance, how many elements are in the `Range` `1.3...2.56`? How much is each step?

In fact, in Swift you *can't* have a `Range` of `Double`s: what you get instead, with the `..<` operator, is a `HalfOpenInterval`, which is a lighter-weight type mainly for checking if something is contained within it.

Making your own version is pretty easy:

```
public struct HalfOpenStartInterval<Bound : Comparable> : IntervalType, Equatable, CustomStringConvertible, CustomDebugStringConvertible {
  public init(_ start: Bound, _ end: Bound) { (self.start, self.end) = (start, end) }
  public let start, end: Bound
  public var description: String {
    return String(reflecting: start) + ">.." + String(reflecting: end)
  }
  public var debugDescription: String { return description }
  @warn_unused_result
  public func contains(x: Bound) -> Bool { return x > start && x <= end }
  @warn_unused_result
  public func clamp(intervalToClamp: HalfOpenStartInterval<Bound>) -> HalfOpenStartInterval<Bound> {
    switch (intervalToClamp.start >= start, intervalToClamp.end <= end) {
    case (true, true)  : return intervalToClamp
    case (false, false): return self
    case (true, false) : return HalfOpenStartInterval(min(intervalToClamp.start, end), end)
    case (false, true) : return HalfOpenStartInterval(start, max(intervalToClamp.end, start))
    }
  }
  public var isEmpty: Bool { return start == end }
}

public func ==<B : Comparable>(lhs: HalfOpenStartInterval<B>, rhs: HalfOpenStartInterval<B>) -> Bool {
  return lhs.start == rhs.start && lhs.end == rhs.end
}
```

Unfortunately, the `>..` operator is reserved, so the initialiser is a little verbose, but here's how you'd use it:

```
let theIntervalIWant = HalfOpenStartInterval(0.0, 1.0)

theIntervalIWant.contains(0.0)      //false
theIntervalIWant.contains(0.0001)   //true
theIntervalIWant.contains(1.0)      //true
```

Answer (score 0):

Ranges are mostly created with an operator. Only these operators are defined in the standard library: `...`, `..<`

So you have to make such operator (`>..`) yourself or just use 0.000000001 instead of 0 which is probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID60), there is only two range operators :

- Closed Range Operator `a...b`
- Half-Open Range Operator `a..<b`

Your question is very interesting and that's why I was search on the internet but I didn't find a pretty simple and cool solution.